# Automatically use \cdot

Tags: symbols

Is there a way to replace the standard multiplication symbol (`*`) with the one `\cdot` shows?
The symbol `\cdot` shows looks much better for me.

Comment: In what context do you mean?  In math mode?  In text mode?  In a particular environment?

Comment: I wouldn't call `*` a standard multiplication symbol, it's used in programming languages but in typeset math it is far more common to use nothing and just juxtapose symbols, or use `\times` or `\cdot`

Comment: * is often used for "secondary commands/environments" like `equation` and `equation*`. Therefore I'm not even sure whether it's possible or not. Even if I would not recommend to change it. If you already used a lot of `*`s, you could use the "find & replace" functionality, that a lot of text editors have. Just replace every ` * ` ( including the spaces!) with `\cdot`. But depending on your document(s), this might not be a good idea …

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\mathcode`\*="8000
{\catcode`\*\active\gdef*{\cdot}}

\begin{document}

It's normal to write $e=mc^2$ but you can write $e=m*c*c$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works until you, for whatever reason, use `\newcommand*` or any other starred macro in math mode.

Comment: @yo' Mmm, I don't think so. This changes the `\mathcode` not the `\catcode`.

Comment: @Manuel Ah ok, you're right.

Comment: @yo' you should have more faith:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Skepticism is the route to knowledge :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The first symbol of `\fnsymbol` (e.g. used in footnotes) is now reduced to a tiny dot ... (`\fnsymbol` sets its symbols in math mode).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like to type the \cdot command, you can use a shortcut that replaces the \cdot. This can be done "outside the LaTeX environment. Like an autocorrection. I'm using these things a lot, because sometimes I'm to lazy to type, but I want to keep the "correct" syntaxis, without some extra things than I will forget in a couple of months.

Answer (score 0):

Since `\cdot` is a `\mathchardef` token, you can just use it to set the mathcode of `*`. You also need to patch `\@fnsymbol`, though, which might use `*` in math mode. Since `\ast` is an alias for `*` in math mode, just change to it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@fnsymbol}{*}{\ast}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@fnsymbol}{*}{\ast}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@fnsymbol}{*}{\ast}{}{}
\makeatother

\mathcode`\*=\cdot

\begin{document}

It's normal to write $e=mc^2$ but you can write $e=m*c*c$.

\end{document}
```

[image]