# How to change "." to \cdot automatically

Tags: symbols, mathcode

By the David Carlisle's answer, [Automatically use \cdot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222976/automatically-use-cdot)
We can input *, TeX turns * into `\cdot` command.
How can I change * by ".".

```
\documentclass{article}
\mathcode`\*="8000
{\catcode`\*\active\gdef*{\cdot}}
\begin{document}
$e=m*c*c$ is equiliant to $e=m\cdot c\cdot c$.

I want to type $e=m.c.c$.
\end{document}
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since `\cdot` is a `\mathchardef` token, you can just use it to set the mathcode of `.`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\mathchardef\mathperiod=\mathcode`.
\mathcode`.=\cdot

\begin{document}

I want to type $e=m.c.c$.

$a\mathperiod b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Saving the original meaning of the period is recommended, in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

Replacing the stars (`*`) with dots (`.`) in the second and third lines of your example seems to do the trick.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\mathcode`\.="8000
{\catcode`\.\active\gdef.{\cdot}}
\begin{document}
$e=m*c*c$ is equiliant to $e=m\cdot c\cdot c$.

I want type $e=m.c.c$.
\end{document}
```

However, I guess this could have side effects I'm not knowledgeable enough to warn you about.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help. Please explain the function of `mathcode` command

Comment: @NamTranLe It's a long topic (it's a bit mask that select the location of the character in a math font, 8000 is "active math character", then you have to learn catcode in TeX to understand the second part, etc.) Read e.g. TeXbook or TeX by topic if you're interested.

Comment: @user202729 Thank you very much. I have read this topic. But I can not understand it.